# Proof strategy for propositional logic algorithm

Tags: algorithms, induction, propositional-calculus

I have to proof the following theorem:

> Proof that $\eta_1 \vee \eta_2 \equiv DISTR(\eta_1, \eta_2)$.

The algorithm DISTR($\eta_1, \eta_2$) is the following:

[image]

Now I want to use induction to prove this, but I don't know how to start with the 2 different propositional formulas $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$. Do I have to use some sort of multidimensional induction (http://www.mathblog.dk/proof-method-multidimensional-induction/) or can I just use induction on the length of $\eta_ \vee \eta_2$?

EDIT: I've tried to proof the theorem by using the tips from the comments and so far I found this:

> We deliver a proof by induction on $rank(\eta_1) + rank(\eta_2)$.
>
> Induction basis: Suppose $rank(\eta_1) + rank(\eta_2) = 0$. This implies that both $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ are atoms. Thus we find ourselves to be in the default case of the algorithm and it returns $\eta_1 \vee \eta_2$.
>
> Induction step: Suppose that $rank(\eta_1) + rank(\eta_2) > 0$. We now have to distinguish different cases:
>
> First case: Suppose $\eta_1 \equiv \eta_a \wedge \eta_b$. We know that $rank(\eta_a) < rank(\eta_1) + rank(\eta_2)$ and $rank(\eta_b) < rank(\eta_1) + rank(\eta_2)$ and $rank(\eta_2) < rank(\eta_1) + rank(\eta_2)$. So by induction, we find that $DISTR(\eta_1, \eta_2) \equiv DISTR(\eta_a, \eta_2) \wedge DISTR(\eta_b, \eta_2)$ and thus $DISTR(\eta_1, \eta_2) \equiv (\eta_a \vee \eta_2) \wedge (\eta_b \vee \eta_2)$.

Now I'm not sure on how to continue... Do I use the distribution-rule on $(\eta_a \vee \eta_2) \wedge (\eta_b \vee \eta_2)$ ? Or did I made a mistake more at the beginning of the proof?

Comment: Use induction on the max complexity (length) of $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$. The structure of your proof will then mimic the structure of the algorithm. I take it the language of the formulas involves variables, $\land$ and $\lor$ only, yes?

Comment: So you mean that I use induction on $max(l(\eta_1), l(\eta_2$))? I'm going to give it a try in that way. Thanks already :)

Comment: In effect, yes, on $\max(len(\eta_1), len(\eta_2))$, or equivalently and more naturally, on "complexity": $\max(rank(\eta_1), rank(\eta_2))$, where  $rank$ is, essentially, the height of the parse tree of a formula. However you choose to think of it, the structure of the proof will be the same.

Comment: PS On further reflection, induct on $rank(\eta_1) + rank(\eta_2)$, as the max isn't necessarily smaller for the recursive calls but the sum will be.

Comment: So I tried to proof the theorem and I modified my question, but I'm still not sure on how to continue. Is my proof correct so far?

Comment: Yes, basically kinda correct, but I felt you didn't quite nail it. The inequialities in the 2nd sentence don't properly set up the use of the induction hypothesis (IH), and you don't explicitly state what the IH lets us conclude about the recursive cases (& probably you should). Rather than critique in comments, I wrote an answer, picking up at the induction step. Feel free to ask (in comments to the answer) if anything is unclear.

Comment: PS It was unclear to me when I just reread it... I fixed a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up at the induction step:

**Case 1:** $\eta_1 = \eta_a\land\eta_b$.

We have $rank(\eta_a), rank(\eta_b) < 1 + \max(rank(\eta_a), rank(\eta_b)) = rank(\eta_1)$, so $$rank(\eta_a) + rank(\eta_2), rank(\eta_b) + rank(\eta_2) < rank(\eta_1) + rank(\eta_2).$$ 
Therefore the induction hypothesis applies to the recursive calls, and we have: $DISTR(\eta_a, \eta_2)\equiv \eta_a \lor \eta_2$ and $DISTR(\eta_b, \eta_2)\equiv \eta_b \lor \eta_2$. Thus:
$$\begin{align}
DISTR(\eta_1, \eta_2) &= DISTR(\eta_a, \eta_2) \land DISTR(\eta_a, \eta_2) \\
&\equiv (\eta_a \lor \eta_2)\land(\eta_b \lor \eta_2) \tag{by IH} \\
&\equiv (\eta_a \land\eta_b) \lor \eta_2 \tag{$\lor$ distributes over $\land$} \\
&= \eta_1 \lor \eta_2.
\end{align}$$

**Case 2:** $\eta_2 = \eta_c\land\eta_d$. Just like Case 1.

**Case 3:** Neither $\eta_1$ nor $\eta_2$ is a conjunction.

Then $DISTR(\eta_1, \eta_2) = \eta_1\lor\eta_2$, so obviously they're equivalent.

Comment: Now I see, thank you very much! I'm going to proof the other cases as well, just as an exercise for myself to practice :)

Comment: Sure, good idea. Too bad there aren't more cases, lol -- really there's only one left. This is a nice problem. (You're welcome, and thank you:)